# Please I received this error on a scrub process “scrub failed, no running scrub jobs”

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, performance-tuning, transactional-replication

Please help it is urgent . The database is also in replication `enter code here`[image]

Comment: There's pretty much 0 information here that anyone would be able to use to help you with. The term "*scrub*" isn't anything specifically related to SQL Server or Replication that I'm aware of, and must be something related to custom or third party software. Please provide a ton of more details, perhaps including the full error message and a screenshot of where you're seeing this message.

Comment: Please see above @J.D. Added a screen shot

Comment: I still don't know what you're showing us here. Seeing exactly what you're looking at would be helpful. Or at least providing the query you ran?

Comment: I ran :  exec check log

Comment: `check log` isn't a native procedure in SQL Server so unfortunately no one here will be able to help you. It probably is something that someone at your company created or installed.

Comment: Please see the answer I've provided below so that if you don't have access to the underlying SSIS package to look inside it, you can at least find if there was an error during the execution of the package. The data you find in the larger query provided will allow you to provide useful information for your question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, that data can come from this query:

```
select
    parameter_name
    ,parameter_value
from
    SSISDB.internal.execution_parameter_values;
```

This shows you the parameters for an SSIS package as set at execution time, rather than the pre-defined values in the package when it's deployed.  If the creator of the package implemented logging external to SSIS, you might find the parameter(s) for that.

As for what is going wrong, you should look at the data in this query. You just give it the project folder and name, the date range, and it'll give you all the messages that SSIS logged during the execution, including errors.

```
declare
    @projectName varchar(128) = 'ProjectName'
    ,@folderName varchar(128) = 'FolderName'
    ,@startDate datetimeoffset = dateadd(d, -1, getdate())
    ,@endDate datetimeoffset = getdate();
    
select
    pr.[name] as projectName
    ,pa.[name] as packageName
    ,ops.server_name as serverName
    ,ops.start_time as startTime
    ,ops.end_time as endTime
    ,case opm.message_type
        when -1 then 'Unknown'
        when 10 then 'Pre-validate'
        when 20 then 'Post-validate'
        when 30 then 'Pre-execute'
        when 40 then 'Post-execute'
        when 50 then 'StatusChange'
        when 60 then 'Progress'
        when 70 then 'Information'
        when 80 then 'VariableValueChanged'
        when 90 then 'Diagnostic'
        when 100 then 'QueryCancel'
        when 110 then 'Warning'
        when 120 then 'Error'
        when 130 then 'TaskFailed'
        when 140 then 'DiagnosticEx'
        when 200 then 'Custom'
        when 400 then 'NonDiagnostic'
        else 'N/A'
    end as messageType
    ,opm.[message]
from
    SSISDB.internal.projects pr
    inner join SSISDB.internal.folders f on pr.folder_id = f.folder_id
    inner join SSISDB.internal.packages pa on pr.project_id = pa.project_id
    and pa.project_version_lsn = pr.object_version_lsn
    inner join SSISDB.internal.operations ops on pr.project_id = ops.[object_id]
    inner join SSISDB.internal.operation_messages opm on ops.operation_id = opm.operation_id
where
    pr.[name] = @projectName
    and f.[name] = @folderName
    and opm.message_time between @startDate and @endDate
order by
    ops.start_time desc;
```

That's the best anyone can help you with, without any additional information. If you find an error in the result set returned by the query above, you can then update your question with those details, and people may be able to help you further.